# Creating/dropping MySQL databases with integer names

Tags: mysql, database

How to create/drop databases which have integers as their names, from the command line? Using GUI clients, I can create/drop them fine. However, 'create/drop database' does not seem to work because the names are integers.

Using GUI clients is fine with me, but curious to know: are there any workarounds to do this in command line?

Note: These databases are created from within an application which is since changed to not create databases with integer names!

Comment: Which version are you using? `mysql -e "create database g10"` just worked fine for me for mysql  5.1

Comment: @David: Does the g in 'g10' signify anything? If not, it's a string. I was looking for ways to make queries like "create database 234" work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use backticks '`' around the name of what you want to drop.  The backtick key is the one that is generally up beside the 1 button on the keyboard.